# Filter on level 2 properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I use **LoopBack** with **MongoDB** connector.

Models:

**Application for a job:**

```
{
    "name": "application",
    "plural": "applications",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "idInjection": true,
    "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
    },
    "properties": {
        "jobId": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        },
        "staffId": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        }
    },
    "validations": [],
    "relations": {},
    "acls": [],
    "methods": {}
}
```

**Job:**

```
{
    "name": "job",
    "plural": "jobs",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "idInjection": true,
    "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
    },
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        }
    },
    "validations": [],
    "relations": {
        "applications": {
            "type": "hasMany",
            "model": "application",
            "foreignKey": "jobId",
            "primaryKey": "id"
        }
    },
    "acls": [],
    "methods": {}
}
```

If the user's id (staffId) is in the applications array I need to not show  for user this job.

**Example:**
We have array of jobs with applications

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Job 1",
    applications: [
      {
        jobId: 1,
        staffId: 1
      },
      {
        jobId: 1,
        staffId: 2
      }
    ] 
  },
  { 
    id: 2,
    title: "Job 2",
    applications: [
      {
        jobId: 2,
        staffId: 1
      }
    ] 
  }
]
```

If user's id (staffId) is 2 then user sees only "Job 2".

I tried something like this:

```
/jobs?filter[include][applications]&filter[where not][applications][elemMatch][staffId]=2
```

But it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At this state of the development you can't filter on a level 2 properties with REST: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/517 (defect till 2014).

What you can do instead is to define a custom emote method that will contain something like:

```
    var userId = 2;
    Jobs.find({
          include: {
                 relation: 'applications',
                       scope: {
                           where: {staffId: {eq: userId}},
                       }
                  }
    }, function (err, jobs) {

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to filter jobs, not applications